# Multiple values for each key in dictionary and updating the values

Tags: python

I got a dictionary and would like to be able to store two values for each key.
One of the values will be added once and the other value be updated by one each time something is true.
So when the key is generated I would like to add a serial number and an extra value that will be updated.
I guess I need to add a list in the dictionary and somehow update the value in the list?

This is the value I would like to add when the key is created:

```
serialnr = getserialnr(x)
```

This code is working but only one value is added and updated for each key.

```
iteration_dic = {}       

for x in range(vlan_start, vlan_end+1):
  connOpen = isOpen(x)
  if connOpen == True:
     if x in iteration_dic:
         print("add to key " + str(x))
         iteration_dic[x] += 1
     else:
         print("create key " + str(x))
         iteration_dic[x] = 1
```

Comment: "I guess I need to add a list in the dictionary and somehow update the value in the list?" Yes. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I was unsure how to do this. I will try suggested solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
iteration_dic = {}       

for x in range(vlan_start, vlan_end+1):
  connOpen = isOpen(x)
  if connOpen == True:
     if x in iteration_dic:
         iteration_dic[x][0] += 1 // or do something else
         iteration_dic[x][1] += 1 // or do something else
     else:
         iteration_dic[x] = [val1, val2]
```